# Background pontilhado ou listrado no css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Alguém me ajuda a fazer um background pontilhado ou listrado no css?

Comment: Vc quer apenas com CSS ou pode usar svg ou png?

Answer (score 1):

Segue o código para criar as listras.
As duas primeiras cores é para a primeira listra, e as duas ultimas cores para a segunda.

```css
div { 
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
90deg,
#000,
#000 10px,
#FFE13A 10px,
#FFE13A 20px
);

width: 900px;
height: 900px;

}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```